# Layover in Canada Airport

Tags: canada, transit-visas, layovers, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipina who will go to Dominica without VISA. Do I still need a transit visa in Canada even though I am just going to stay in the Aiport for 19 hrs? I am not going outside at the airport.

Comment: Yes, you need a transit visa according to http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp

Comment: Canada's "transit without visa" programs are only available for people transiting to or from the US, who are traveling on passports from Indonesia, Philippines, Thailand, Taiwan, and China. Since you are not transiting to or from the US, those do not apply to you. So you need a visa if your passport would normally need a visa to visit the US.